# WebClient's bodyToMono error

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am making an external api call with Spring 5 WebClient and would like to map the response to an Object like this:

```
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public static class Response {
    private long length;
}

private Mono<Response> getResponse() {
    return webClient.get()
            .uri("someURI")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(Response.class);
}
```

But I get an error:

```
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.UnsupportedMediaTypeException: Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported
```

However if I extract response body to String like this:

```
private Mono<String> getResponse() {
return webClient.get()
        .uri("someURI")
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(String.class); 
}
```

Then it works properly. Any ideas how to solve this?

**EDIT**:

Response body:

```
{
  "blocks": [
  {
  "height": 545551,
  "size": 48289,
  "virtualSize": 48289,
  "hash": "000000000000000000541d265115ec188544420c4b0e5dff6f2171e17e4991c9",
  "time": 1535551238,
  "txlength": 80,
  "poolInfo": {}
  }
  ],
  "length": 1,
  "pagination": {
  "next": "2018-08-30",
  "prev": "2018-08-28",
  "currentTs": 1535587199,
  "current": "2018-08-29",
  "isToday": true,
  "more": true,
  "moreTs": 1535587200
  }
}
```

Headers:

```
status: 200 OK
```

Comment: there's no Content-Type response header?

Comment: @BrianClozel yes, that was the case, changed the api to the one with Content-Type header and it all worked, thanks ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the HTTP response doesn't have a `Content-Type` header, the client will assume `application/octet-stream`, which is not a Content-Type that's supported by the Jackson codec in Spring WebFlux.

So the behavior you're seeing is the expected one, and the web API should be fixed to add a response header.

Comment: You could reconfigure the codecs (see `ClientCodecConfigurer`) or add a `WebFilter` that changes the Content-Type of the response in some cases. It really depends on what your client is requesting and how the remote server is behaving